# Why the default value of notifyObersver is ALWAYS?

Tags: cdi, observer-pattern, java-ee-7

Based on Java EE 7 document, the `@Observes` annotation has `ALWAYS` or `IF_EXISTS` as the value of `notifyObserver` attribute.

**Question 1**: Why the default value is `ALWAYS`? what is the sense of notifying to the observer if the observer bean instance does not exist yet?

**Question 2**: what real world use case of `IF_EXISTS` could there be?

Answer (score 0):

While I wasn't there to make the call, I guess it was a design choice for two reasons I can think of.

Firstly, you can have `@Dependent` beans with observers and these beans never truly 'exist' on their own as a new intance is created for whichever other bean injects them. For the record, an observer on a dependent bean means a new instance of that bean will always be created to notify the observer and then destroyed. `IF_EXISTS` wouldn't be possible to achieve meaning it would by default not work for those beans.

Secondly, you can choose to observe a lifecycle event such as initialization of a context (`@Initialized(ApplicationScope.class`). And for context such as application context, there is no bean active sooner than that - you couldn't actually observe the event itself. Or, for other contexts, you'd be limited to putting those observers into bean with 'wider' scope (i.e. an observer for req. context would need to be in a bean with application scope).

There is maybe more limitations but these I can think of from the top of my head. Therefore, having `ALWAYS` as default value is way less restrictive and, I suppose, fits more user scenarios out of the box.

As for the added question of `IF_EXISTS` use cases - the only use case I can think of is changing internal state of a bean based on events delivered during its lifecycle. I.e. imagine a session scoped bean with `IF_EXISTS` observer for event type `Foo`. Once the bean exists (== once you are inside an active session), it gets notified for every `Foo` event that happens which can serve as either a counter or perhaps `Foo` contains some metadata you want to keep track of during the session.
I imagine there will be more cases but this one I know I've come across.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Just continuing with your last statement, the `ALWAYS` fits more use cases, could you give any real world use case of using `IF_EXISTS`? I added that question also to the question body :)

Comment: I've edited my answer to include that